# tell ssh to only use a single key

Tags: ssh

I have a test server set up with basic SSH.

If I run the following command I cannot log in:

`ssh root@localhost`

This results in:

> Too many authentication failures for root

If I use the following, it **succeeds**:

`ssh root@localhost -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive,password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no`

I believe there is an issue in my **~/.ssh/config** file, which is set up as follows:

```
Host my-server.my-domain.com
  User eln00b
  HostName 1.2.3.4
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myserver

Host my-server-prod.my-domain.com
  User eln00b
  HostName 1.2.3.5
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myserver
  ForwardAgent yes

Host github.com-eln00b
  User git
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
```

Any obviously location of the conflict causing me to need the extra options for ssh?

Comment: Do you have an SSH agent enabled?  How many keys do you have loaded into your agent?  Have you tried connecting with `ssh -vv root@localhost`?  It should show you each authentication method it is attempting.

Comment: I ran `ssh-add -L` and it looks like I have 6 entries.  Running with `-vv` shows me a bunch of key attempts.   So it looks like that is interfering.  Running after `ssh-agent -k` causes the ssh request to just hand, which seems to be progress.  I will need to figure out that now.